# VM with two NIC on Hyper-V - how to do that?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, vlan

I'm new to Hyper-V.  How do you configure two IP address on the same VM server?  Both IP are on different subnets - one in 192.168.x.x and the other 10.x.x.x.  There is an uplink (802.1q) between the Hyper-V physical server and the Cisco switch.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean on the guest virtual machine? You do it the same as you do on a physical server. Is this guest connected to two virtual switches? Do you have two physical network cards in the host and have you created an external virtual switch for each of the host network cards?

Comment: you mention 802.1q do you want to create a trunk between you Switch and the Hyper V host server? with each port in a different VLAN or just create a trunk for redundancy?

Answer (score 1):

If you just have one cable running to the Hyper-V host and you just have one virtual switch, you can just add the second IP in the advanced IPv4 settings of the network adapter in your VM.

If you have multiple network adapters and connections on your host, it will require a little more.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this, or where can one find info about the configuration on the Hyper-V manager / virtual switch side?

Answer (score 1):

Is this question about the HyperV Host server or a Virtual Machine on the HyperV host Server?

Are you running Server 2012 or 2012 R2?

If for the HyperV Host Server - How many NICs do you have in you HyperV host server? you say that you have a DOT1Q connection from you CISCO Switch so you imply you want to create a trunk? If you have multiple NICS in your server I would consider creating a NIC team. you can use the first team interface and assign an IP address and a VLAN number then you create a 2nd team interface and assign a separate IP Address and VLAN number for that.

There is some information on here about creating NIC teams:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831648(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> How do you configure two IP address on the same VM server?

You just add them? I mean, same like any normal windows - just add the multiple IP addresses and routing (and there can only be one default route).

You can do so using the graphical tools, or he command line (powershell https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/new-netipaddress?view=win10-ps).